# How do I scope and obtain admin authorization for my Microsoft Graph API daemon from my admin team?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a specific SharePoint site that I have been asked to integrate my web based application with in a `read-only` fashion using my backend server.

I currently have an app with Default Directory only (Single tenant) access
which I am modifying Application API permissions to also require `Sites.Selected`, however this one is requiring that I obtain Admin consent

I have had an absolute atrocious time trying to figure out how to obtain access to my specific site and not grant access to every single site in my tenant

I'm working on a dummy azure account prior to asking my ops team for the real permissions from the real ecosystem, but I dont have a sharepoint site to test on because I dont know how to set it up, the IT department team who manages it is very slow to answer so its difficult to move the ball forward without knowing exactly what I need before asking.

[image]

Under "Enterprise Applications" > {My Application Name } > Permissions (left sidebar), i see a big blue button that I read about in some docs, but i'm scared to grant the permissions because it says I give my app access to the `default` directory which I don't want to do, and it provides nowhere for me to specify my "selected" site

does anyone have more information on how I can grant a specific site to my app?

every article I run to talks about admin confirmation but neglects to tell me specifically how it's done

Answer (score 0):

`Default Directory` is just a default name for your tenant, and not related to any default collection of sites. See my tenant name `v6pz1` in the image

[image]

For this `Sites.Selected` permission, it's a 2-step process for giving your app access to the sites.

1. The app needs to be given permission to the site at the SharePoint level
2. The app needs to be granted admin consent to access the sites through the Graph API

You see this described in the [MS Graph permissions reference table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-57) as well.

> Allow the application to access a subset of site collections without a signed in user.  The specific site collections and the permissions granted will be configured in SharePoint Online.

To actually grant your app the SharePoint permission to a site, you can use the MS Graph endpoint to [create permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-post-permissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Just checking if I follow, do I need to grant the default directory as my step 1?

Comment: The order of these 2 steps has no bearing in this scenario

Comment: regardless - i DO need to add the default directory though?

Comment: You need to grant admin consent for your tenant named Default Directory for the Sites.Selected permission, yes